# Audit log on GCP for user authenticate with Google signin

Tags: google-signin

Is there a log on GCP of the users that tried to authenticate with google-signin ?
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

meaning users that press the widget and see if they managed to pass the google authentication or failed.

I was looking on GCP for those logs but couldn't find, wasn't sure if they don't exist or I should enable them somehow.